# PHP - how to put query results in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to put a mysql query result into an array that can be accessed outside the while loop. Is this possible?

My test code that I am playing with is below. I want to send email to the email addresses in the array without creating the email code inside the while loop. That way I can inject the array result into the BCC field and it all goes out at once using the mail() function rather than opening a new smtp connection for each email - or so I think.

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['btnSendToSelected']) && isset($_POST['checked']))
{
    $checked = array_map('intval',$_POST['checked']);
    $email_list = implode(", ", $checked);

    $get_emails = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserName, Email FROM users WHERE UserId IN ($email_list)")
    or die($dataaccess_error);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails))
    {
        $emails = array($row['Email']);
        $emails_array = implode(", ", $emails);
    }
        // send the email here outside the while loop...
}
elseif(isset($_POST['btnSendToSelected']) && !isset($_POST['checked']))
{
    $msg = $msg_error;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$emails_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails)) {
    $emails_array[] = explode(", ", $row['Email']);
}

foreach($emails_array as $value) {
  mail_function($value);
}
```

Or

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails)) {
  foreach(explode(", ", $row['Email']) as $value) {
    mail_function($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution answers the question as asked.  I'm still not sure it is the correct solution for the end goal however...

Comment: Added a nested version for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

```
$emails_array = implode(", ", $emails);
```

You can `explode` this line wherever you want to get your array.

//EDIT

It looks like that whole `while` loop can be handled a bit better.  I suggest

```
$emails = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails))
    {
        $emails[] = $row['Email']."|||".$row['Username'];
    }
```

Then you've got all the info in the `$emails` array in one go.

The `|||` is just a random delimiter I chose, You could use a comma or something.  Alternatively, you could make that entry a 2-d array, something like

```
$emails[][0] = $row['Email'];
$emails[][1] = $row['Username'];
```

...although that specific code probably won't work, the idea will.  Then, just access it like this:

```
echo "Username 99 is ".$emails[99][1];
```

Comment: Was about to post the exact same thing with one addendum - after the loop, you can create the list of email addresses for the BCC field using `$emailList = implode(', ', $emails);`

Comment: Thanks for taking the high road and not duplicating my post.  That's been happening (to me) a lot lately so I really appreciate the chance to be +1ed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The email is still stored in the variable $row.  And $email...  You can also do this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails))
{
    mail($row['Email'],$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

If you want to store the emails in an array:

```
$emails = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emails))
{
    $emails[] = $row['Email'];
}
```

Comment: but when I echo out the array, it only shows a single email address. if I echo it from inside the loop, I get them all.

Comment: Check out that edit...  this populates an array with the emails.  You can access them by looping through the array or calling them by their numeric array key.

Comment: yeah, none of these seems to work for me. sorry I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.